# Python graphics library for grid display

Tags: python, graphics

We have an appointment schedule that fills up and I would like to display information about each square, graphically.   See the picture.

I would love to find a graphics library that I can access via Python to build out something like this and update it.  Note that each "cell" in the grid has multiple values we'd like to display.

Could you advise on libraries that may be appropriate for this task and the learning curve for a back-end dev forced to do front-end work?

[image: gridpic]

Comment: Unrelated, but you might find this helpful in answering the question you just deleted: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187332/is-changing-the-type-of-a-variable-partway-through-a-procedure-in-a-dynamically?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it's something that you are looking for but would something like Tkinter or Kivi work? Both of them are GUI libraries and Kivi can be used to convert your programme into a mobile app.

You could potentially use PyGame and use it to create a cell using it.

Comment: Kivy is brilliant and perfect for this -- thanks, Eugene.

Comment: Np, glad I was able to help